# How to plot points using interrelated distances?

Tags: python, dictionary, plot

I have a dictionary of points:

```
dictDistances = {A:{B:1.23, C:3.56}, B:{A:1.23, C:2.38}, C:{A:3.56, B:2.38}}
```

And I would like to plot them without using the absolute values, i.e. using the values from the dictionary. I can draw that, but I don't understand, how to do that in Python.

***There are much more than 3 points, like 300, I've just added this dictionary in order to demonstrate the kind of information I have.

****My points (each of 3) may not or may satisfy the triangle inequality theorem

UPDATE

What it's going to look like, given points A, B, C, D, E, F and some distances of range from x:y between them:

[image]

On the image provided you can see sets of all distances, i.e:

```
AB AC AD AF AE
BA BC BD BF BE
CB CA CD CF CE
DB DC DA DF DE
EB EC ED EF EA
FB FC FD FA FE
```

UPDATE 2

Rays:
Ray A:

[image]

Ray B:

[image]

Ray C:

[image]

And the same for the rays E,D,F. Then I need to verify/modify them somehow. That's what I don't understand how to do in Python. Though it is absolutely possible to draw.

Comment: I am very confused as to how you want to plot them. And this format. Is it your intention to do a scatter plot with each point being a combination of the 2 values? What would determine which value is plotted on the X axis and which on the Y axis? The values themselves are in dictionaries, which are unordered...

Comment: Well, pretty much like drawing a point A, then I know that B is 1.23 from and C is 3.56 from A. In such a way I can draw them on one line. However, after I get the value for distance between B and C, which is 2.38, AB and AC no longer lie on the same line. And what's wrong with the dictionary?

Comment: Do you have an example of what you want it to look like?

Comment: @mauve, please see the update

Comment: Since you're looking at distances, rather than coordinates, I'm confused as to how you're locating any given point at a unique spot in space instead of simply at a radius from the first point...how would one determine that B is SE of A, and not NW or SW or NE of A?

Comment: @mauve 1)that's why I actually asked. But I have no absolute coordinates in any case; 2) I think that they should be mapped on one line,first, like A initial point of the ray and all the other points with their corresponding distances on ray A. Same for B, same for C... etc. And then verify the rays by each other

Comment: @Anna-Lischen did you ever find a useful solution to this? I'm trying to plot the trees in our wood by measuring the distance between each tree and 2-4 of its neighbors. I'm curious what your approach ended up being.

Comment: @Dunstan jusr look at the accepted answer. I guess I used it and modded my code. It's been a long time since though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you need to do is:

- generate a dictionary that pairs up the point, distance for each point. i.e.

Dict_comp[A] = set((B, 1.3), (C, 9.5), (D, 20.3)) etc...

- force point A to be at the origin (0,0)
- choose a direction for the first point you want to plot. For instance, I would plot B at (1.3, 0).
- once you have those first 2 points plotted, determine the coordinates for each other point based on their relationship to the first 2.

  - with the dictionary existing with each point's distance from the others known, you would look up Dict_comp[C] and check the distance from existing points to get that info.

[This example from matplotlib will help you with polar coordinates](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pie_and_polar_charts/polar_scatter_demo.html) - you'll have r from each of two existing points, then you can figure out theta. I wouldn't ever use more than two existing points to locate a third, given this info.